# 3D touch (Peek & Pop) does not work in non collapsed UISplitViewController (landscape iPhone 6s Plus)

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, touch, uisplitviewcontroller

I can't get Peek & Pop to work, when the source view for Peek & Pop is the DetailViewController of a UISplitViewController in non collapsed state on iPhone 6s Plus (landscape, Regular horizontal trait enviroment.). The Peek & Pop gesture is just ignored.
Peek & Pop works fine in Portrait (collapsed state, compact horizontal trait environment).

The source code for the sample application demonstrating this issue, you can download at: https://github.com/hholtmann/SplitViewPeekPop

To reproduce the issue you have to run the sample app on an iPhone 6s Plus in landscape mode. The Peek & Pop functionality is implemented for the image thumbnails.

I would be glad for any hints&tips how to get this to work.

Comment: Have you noticed that none of apple's native apps (e.g. mail, messages, etc.) offer this functionality in the given context? Leads me to believe it's not supported.

Comment: The mail and messages app already shows the "full" message/mail in landscape mode. So there is no reason to offer peek & pop in these cases. I wouldn't conclude from this, that Peel & Pop is is generally not supported in a non collapsed UISplitViewController.

Comment: send yourself a url. try to peek and pop the url in the detailviewcontroller in portrait. works. in landscape. no. why wouldn't they implement it if it's supported?

Comment: Ok. I don't have a 6s Plus on hand right now. It's a strange design decision though and self.view.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability gives UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable also in landscape. So something is definitely messed up.

Comment: I don't disagree. Peek and pop works in landscape just not split view uncollapsed. Think it has to do with if you commit it creates a uinavigationcontroller so the user can press back and return to previous view. In split view if the user rotates back to portrait there is a question as to what back is, as in whether it's the master view controller or detail view controller.